# Swift-using C libraries and build command error on ubuntu

Tags: linux, swift, ubuntu, module, libraries

I am new to Linux and to Swift and I have encountered a problem.
I am learning with a book called "Mastering Swift 3 for Linux" and I am at chapter 13 where I am supposed to create a module and then write some code and build a .exe file. So when I use the `~/swift build` command an error occurs saying:

```
Fetching /home/bohdan/Cpcap
Cloning /home/bohdan/Cpcap
Resolving /home/bohdan/Cpcap at 0.1.0
Compile Swift Module 'pcapProject' (1 sources)
945045102700753156/module.modulemap
:3:8: error: header '/usr/include/pcap.h' not found
header "/usr/include/pcap.h"
:1:8: error: could not build `Objective-C module 'Cpcap'


import Cpcap

<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /opt/swift/Swift123/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f `/home/bohdan/pcapProject/.build/debug.yaml
```

How I understand it is the problem here is that there is no pcap.h header in the include directory but I was following my book step-by-step while creating the pcap module so I don't really know if it should be there and if so then what should be in this file.

Comment: Did you install the libpcap-dev package?

Comment: Yes, I did. install this package.

Comment: Does `/usr/include/pcap.h` exist?

Comment: No, it does not. That is the problem here.